# Erroneous argument that every distribution function is left continuous.

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

I am trying to understand the distribution function, and read that it normally is only right continuous. But somehow I get left continuity as well, so could somebody please tell me what I am doing wrong: What is wrong with this 'proof'?

Let X be a r.v.

Take an arbitrary x and let $x_n\to x$ be monotonically increasing. Then
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}F_X(x_n)=\lim_{n\to\infty}P^{X}((-\infty,x_n])=\lim_{n\to\infty}\int\mathbb{1}_{(-\infty,x_n]}dP^{X}$$

now monotone convergence gives

$$=\int\mathbb{1}_{(-\infty, x]}dP^{X}=F_X(x)$$

hence $F_X$ is left continuous.

Comment: $$\bigcup_n (-\infty,x_n] = (-\infty, x) \neq (-\infty, x]$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should find that $$1_{(-\infty, x_n]} \rightarrow 1_{(-\infty, x)}.$$

Comment: If $(x_n)_n$ is such that $x_n<x \forall n$. Yes I see now. Thank you.